# Get rid off from matching record and add not equal data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following tables:

Table a:

```
Name 

T1      
T2     
T3
T4
```

Table b:

```
Name 
T1      
T2     
T3
T4
T5
T6
```

I need to select all from table a and add what is not in table a from table b, result below:

```
T1      
T2     
T3
T4
T5
T6
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are there duplicates in table a? if there are duplicate in table a do you want the result too to have the same duplicates? How about table b?

Comment: There is no duplicate in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with an anti-join (a NOT IN condition). As written below, it will not work correctly if `NULL` is possible in that column in table `a` (in that case, the anti-join should be written with a `NOT EXISTS` condition). I assume the column is `NOT NULL`.

An anti-join is faster than a join, because as soon as a value from table `b` is also found in `a`, the joining for that row of table `b` stops and processing moves on to the next row. In a join, the joining continues, there is no such short-circuiting.

Oto's solution uses a join rather than an anti-join. However, I believe the Oracle query optimizer recognizes, in this simple case, that an anti-join is sufficient, and it will rewrite the query to use an anti-join. This is something you can verify by running Explain Plan on both queries. With that said, in a similar but much more complicated problem, the optimizer may not be able to "see" this shortcut; this is why I believe it's best to write anti-joins (and semi-joins, where we use `IN` or `EXISTS` conditions) explicitly, rather than rely on the optimizer.

The query should be

```
select name from a
union all
select name from b where name not in ( select name from a );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all unique names from both the tables, use `UNION`:

```
select name from table_a
union
select name from table_b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
select ta.name from ta
union all
select tb.name from tb
left join  ta
on tb.name = ta.name
where ta.name is null
```

Comment: This is probably the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that:

```
Select distinct Name
from (
select Name from Table A
UNION ALL
select Name from Table B
)
```

Comment: Although accurate, this is unnecessarily complicated, because a simple `union` does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, is there any other ways, with distinct its slow

Comment: thanks all for different approach. To mathguy: thanks, I'll test it, looks good.